# how to remap S to shift ( in Vim?

Tags: vim, key

To go forward a sentence in Vim you have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>(</kbd>
to go back a sentence <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd>
How can I remap this to avoid having to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>?
I was hoping to remap something like `s` to equal <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd>
how can I do that, I dont know the symbol to represent <kbd>Shift</kbd> when remapping I tried `nnoremap s <shift>(` but it didn't work

Comment: `:nnoremap s (` and `:nnoremap s )` both work perfectly for me. What version of Vim are you using?

Comment: `Shift+9` is `(`. `Shift+(` isn't anything.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're indeed complicating things

```
:nnoremap S (
:nnoremap s )
```

would do the obvious things (at least on my vim 7.3)